# How to set fixed position to DIV into the page

Tags: jquery, css, html

I have a CSS box-model like this:
[image]

Using jQuery (when a button is cliecked) I resize my Main Content Div, but the footer doesn't maintain its position at the bottom of the screen:

[image]

I try to set `position: fixed` to footer div, but it doesn't scroll with the page.

I would like to know if there is a way to position the footer regardless of the content

Comment: `Using jQuery` and where is you jquery code??

Comment: please post your html structure and the css

Comment: could you paste your css and html code?

Comment: This should be easily possible with CSS alone. Please post your current HTML + CSS

Comment: Write the Footer `<div>` outside the content `<div>`

Answer (score 0):

Use css to achieve this

```
.my_footer {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    height: 100px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

TRY THIS

http://jsfiddle.net/8pjdp/1/

CSS

```
.footer{
background-color:#76D6FF;
position:fixed;
bottom:0;
    width:100%;
    height:100px;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="footer">footer</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
.class_name {
    width:100%;
    height:100px;        
    position:fixed;
    bottom:0;
    background-color: #CCC;
}
```